# Delete row based on another table col value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

I thought this would be easy but my code doesn't work.

I want to delete all rows in table1 containing name returned by `select * from table2` where member='no'` if the name is 'Simon'. ie remove all non-members beginning with 'S'.

`table1`:

```
name, age 
jane, 29 
simon, 30 
jessica, 20
```

`table2`:

```
name, member
jane, yes
simon, no
jessica, no
```

Resulting table1 is

```
name, age
jane, 29
jessica, 30
```

My attempts to date are

```
delete from table1 
where name = 'Simon' and table2.Member = 'No'
```

This gives me an error

> The multi-part identifier "Tools.Htf" could not be bound

Next I tried joining the tables then deleting

```
DELETE FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 T1 ON O
```

But this doesn't seem to make syntactical sense at all.

Comment: Are you trying to delete the person from both tables or just table1?

Comment: No, just the one, table1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this is how you are trying to do. Give it a try

```
DELETE w
FROM table1 w
INNER JOIN table2 e
  ON w.name=e.name
Where w.name LIKE 's%' AND e.Member='No'
```

Comment: But will 'Delete w...' not delete the entire table?

Comment: @Fearghal, Why will it delete entire table? What for the where condition used then?

Comment: i saw this slution before and figured that 'w' was the table as it says '...from table1 w...' ie table1 alias is w so delete w...would delete the entire table. I think i had other issues where my SSMS was alerting incorrectly that the table didnt exist and so the rest of th equery looked like it would fail but this worked a treat. thx

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, sorry but not getting why would `w.name LIKE 's%'` be much help but if you think that's the right way then you are welcome to edit my answer.

Comment: @Rahul Simply that the question says `remove all non-members beginning with 'S'.`, which `w.name='Simon'` will not do. For example, another non member called Sarah won't be deleted.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Ahh!! I missed that. Thank You for pointing that. Edited now accordingly. Anyways, feel free to edit my answer if it makes the answer better and more accurate.